# How to center my footer

Tags: html, css

My footer needs to be centered, but it won't.
I used a template from Puremedia and changed a few things, but I'm at a loss and need this to be fixed asap.

My footer right now happens to look like this:

http://tinypic.com/r/e0hdgi/8

The footer needs to be pushed left like this:

http://tinypic.com/r/2lu2qu0/8

Here's my code.

```css
/* i. Footer Styles
/* =================================================================== */
footer {
 padding-top: 36px;
 padding-bottom: 42px;
 font-size: 13px;
 line-height: 24px;
 color: #3C4142; 
}

footer a, footer a:visited {
 color: #a43b0a;
}
footer a:hover, footer a:focus {
 color: white;
}
footer h3 {
 font: 13px/24px "raleway-bold", sans-serif;
 margin-bottom: 0;
 color: white;
 text-transform: uppercase;
 letter-spacing: 1px;
}
footer p {
 margin: 12px 0;
}

footer .footer-about {
 padding-right: 60px;
}
footer .right-cols .columns {
 width: 50%;
 word-wrap: break-word;
}
footer ul {
 margin: 12px 0;
 padding: 0;
 list-style: none;
}
footer ul li {
 margin: 0;
 padding-left: 0;
 line-height: 24px;
}
footer ul li a, footer ul li a:visited {
 color: #3C4142;
}
footer .copyright {
 margin: 0;
 padding: 24px 18px 6px 18px;
 clear: both;
}

/* back to top */
footer #go-top {
 position: fixed;
 bottom: 0;
 right: 30px;
 z-index: 900;
 display: none;
}
footer #go-top a {
 display: block;
 padding: 12px 30px;
 background: #d44d0d;
 color: white;
 text-align: center;
 font: 12px/24px "raleway-heavy", sans-serif;
 text-transform: uppercase;
 letter-spacing: 2px;
 -moz-transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
 -o-transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
 -webkit-transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
 -ms-transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
 transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
}
footer #go-top a span {
 margin-right: 10px;
}
footer #go-top a:hover {
 background: #faec09;
 color: #252525;
}
```

```html
 <!-- Footer
   ================================================== -->
 <footer>
      <div class="row">       
         <div class="six columns tab-whole footer-about">            
        <h3>Site Map</h3>
               <!--Links on the NAV-->
        <li><a href="index.html">HOME</a></li>
        <li><a href="register.html">REGISTRATION</a></li>
        <li><a href="audition.html">AUDITION</a></li>
        <li><a href="contact.html">CONTACT</a></li>
        <li><a href="credits.html">CREDITS</a></li>                                                   
         </div> 

         <div class="six columns tab-whole right-cols">

            <div class="row">

               <div class="columns">
                  <h3>TAB 2</h3>                      
                  <ul>
                    <li><a href="http://www.ncmea.net">NCMEA</a></li>
                    <li><a href="">123.456.7890</a></li>
                    <li><a href="mailto:someone@puremedia.com">someone@puremedia.com</a></li>
                  </ul>                  
               </div> <!-- /columns -->             
               <div class="columns last">
                  <h3 class="contact">TAB 3</h3>
                  <ul>
                     <li><a href="#crash">Link 1</a></li>
                     <li><a href="#crash">Link 2</a></li>
                     <li><a href="#crash">Link 3</a></li>
                     <li><a href="#crash">Link 4</a></li>
                     <li><a href="#crash">Link 5</a></li>
                     <li><a href="#crash">Link 6</a></li>
                  </ul>                      
               </div> <!-- /columns --> 
            </div> <!-- /Row(nested) -->
         </div>
   <center>
         <p class="copyright">&copy; Copyright 2015 Billy & Carter. CSS template design by <a href="http://www.styleshout.com/">Styleshout.</a></p>        
   </center>
         <div id="go-top">
            <a class="smoothscroll" title="Back to Top" href="index.html"><span>Back to top</span><i class="fa fa-long-arrow-up"></i></a>
         </div>
      </div> <!-- /row -->
   </footer> <!-- /footer -->
```

Comment: I looked only quickly but In the css footer I did not see something like margin: auto; or margin-left:x px/%;  margin-right:x px/%; maybe try with that

Comment: The footer is in fact centered, it just might not appear that way since there are no visible edges of the main page "area" to compare with.

Comment: Thanks Keikoku, I'll test it out to see if that worked. 
Also Perplexor, I didn't know how to describe it. I just need it to have the right two columns fixed and pushed left.

Comment: Tag `<center>` is deprecated... you should use `CSS` instead of it...

Comment: Can't you give more code? I tried your code in jsfiddle but it stays uggly as this, and it's hard to simulate what you want :/ http://jsfiddle.net/nq7n2ec5/

Comment: Pedro, that's the only css that goes with the HTML.
Nothing else goes with it...